# install libdivxencore-devel-0.4.0.50.tbz

Tags: software-installation

after extraction I got: lib, include, +comment, +contents, +desc. +mtree_dirs ... any suggestion instead ./configure (I tried all I got after extraction ) will be a good gesture, in fact I installed only  files with .deb format

Comment: you can install it by `sudo apt-get install divxenc`

Comment: xine couldn't find demux and vide_out:can't raice nice priority by 2,plus video_decoder: can't rice nice priority by 1